# Let $f\in P_2(\mathbb R)$ Let $T[f(x)] = f(0)+f(1)(x+x^2)$. Is T diagonolizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $f\in P_2(\mathbb R)$, the space of second-order polynomials with real coefficients, and let the linear operator $T$ be defined as $T[f(x)] = f(0)+f(1)(x+x^2)$.

Is $T$ diagonalizable? If so, find a basis $\beta$ of $P_2(\mathbb R)$ in which $[T]_\beta$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Let
\begin{align*}                                                                                 
e_1(t) &= 1 & e_2(t) &= t & e_3(t) &= t^2                                                      
\end{align*}
and note that $\alpha=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ is a basis for $P_2(\Bbb R)$. Furthermore,
note that
\begin{array}{lclclcl}
T(e_1) & = & \color{red}{1}\,e_1 & + & \color{green}{1}\,e_2 & + & \color{blue}{1}\,e_3 \\
T(e_2) & = & \color{red}{0}\,e_1 & + & \color{green}{1}\,e_2 & + & \color{blue}{1}\,e_3 \\
T(e_3) & = & \color{red}{0}\,e_1 & + & \color{green}{1}\,e_2 & + & \color{blue}{1}\,e_3
\end{array}
This implies that the matrix of $T$ relative to    $\alpha$ is
$$
[T]_\alpha=
\begin{bmatrix}
\color{red}{1} & \color{red}{0} & \color{red}{0} \\
\color{green}{1} & \color{green}{1} & \color{green}{1} \\
\color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{1} & \color{blue}{1}
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now, $T$ is diagonalizable if and only if $[T]_\alpha$ is diagonalizable. Can
you determine if $[T]_\alpha$ is diagonalizable? If so, what is the change of
basis matrix and how does it relate to your desired basis $\beta$?

Answer (score 1):

We need to find eigenvectors. 
Since the image of $T$ is inly twodimensional, it is clear that one eigenvalue must be $0$. Indeed, $f(x)=x\cdot(x-1)=x^2-x$ is obviously in the kernel of $T$ (and the kernel consists precicely of the multiple of this - why?)

It should be clear from the definition of $T$ that all eigenvectors to nonzero eigenvalues have the form $f(x)=a+bx+bx^2$ (because $T[f]$ has this form). Observe that $f(x)=a+bx+bx^2$ implies $f(0)=a$ and $f(1)=a+2b$, so that $T[f]=a+(a+2b)(x+x^2)$, $T[f](0)=a$, and $T[f](1)=3a+4b$.
Therefore if $a\ne0$ then the eigenvalue $\lambda$ must be $1$ and we must have $b=a+2b$, i.e., $b=-a$. We conclude that the eigenvectors of eigenvalue $1$ are precisely the multiples of $1-x-x^2$.
Remains the case $a=0$ and necessarily $b\ne0$; we see that such $f$ is eigenvector of eigenvalue $2$.

In conclusoin, we have found a basis of eigenvectors
$$\beta\begin{cases}&x^2-x&\lambda=0\\
&x^2+x-1&\lambda=1\\
&x^2+x&\lambda=2\end{cases}$$
so that $T$ with respect to this basis is in fact diagonal: $$[T]_\beta=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&2\end{pmatrix}.$$

Answer (score 0):

You can write the operator in a matrix form by considering the action of this operator on $1$, $x$ and $x^2$ which is the standard basis for second-order polynomials.Then all you need to do is to deal with the eigenvectors of that matrix.